# How to set image height on a button in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Click here to see the desired design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmrTi.png)

I want a footer structure like above (desired design) in my application which has two button with 50% width and fb and google image on it. But i can not set the height of the image. Please help me out

Here is my tried code

```
<StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <!-- top controls -->
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- middle controls -->
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text="Has Image" Image="drawable/fb_btn.png"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text="Sign Up"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **HeightRequest** in your code like that:

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Name="imageBtn" Text="Has Image" Image="drawable/fb_btn.png" 
                  HeightRequest="56"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

More info:

1,Your code contain StackLayout ,it also can modify the result.

2,If you want more control over the image size and placement,you can add a tap gesture recognizer to it.

**.CS**

```
TapGestureRecognizer tapEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapEvent.Tapped += Button_Clicked;
imageBtn.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**workaround**

1.You can use Image control with a tapgesture:

XAML

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="myPicture.png" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

XAML.CS

```
TapGestureRecognizer tapEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapEvent.Tapped += clickedEvent;
myImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapEvent);
```

2. refer to https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton